# Why doesn't session work when cookie is disabled?

Tags: php, session, cookies

According to my knowledge, session is stored at server and cookie is stored at client. But as soon as cookie is disabled, the session stops working. What is the reason behind this? Is it possible to make session work when cookie is disabled?

Few references I got:
http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Comment: What technique do you think a server can use to identify a session among different requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, because when cookie is disabled, the server has no idea which sessions a client belongs to (no information of the session is passed to the server). If you want to make session work when cookie is disabled, you may have to pass a PHPSESSID in your urls, something that looks like this:

```
http://example.com/myurl.php?PHPSESSID=[a long string]
```

PHPSESSID can be generated by using session_id() function.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the cookie is used to identify which session on the server is associated with the current client.